# Group Laravel Collection By Children

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, collections

I was wondering if its possible to use laravel collections to group items that have the same children. If you look at the example below I'd like to group orders with id 1 and 4 together as well as 2 and 3 together. The order with id 5 would be in its own group. Does this make sense?

```
$orders = collect([
    [
        'id' => 1,
        'items' => [
            ['id' => 1, 'name' => 'Product A'],
            ['id' => 2, 'name' => 'Product B']
        ]
    ],
    [
        'id' => 2,
        'items' => [
            ['id' => 3, 'name' => 'Product C'],
            ['id' => 4, 'name' => 'Product D']
        ]
    ],
    [
        'id' => 3,
        'items' => [
            ['id' => 3, 'name' => 'Product C'],
            ['id' => 4, 'name' => 'Product D']
        ]
    ],
    [
        'id' => 4,
        'items' => [
            ['id' => 1, 'name' => 'Product A'],
            ['id' => 2, 'name' => 'Product B']
        ]
    ],
    [
        'id' => 5,
        'items' => [
            ['id' => 1, 'name' => 'Product A'],
            ['id' => 2, 'name' => 'Product B'],
            ['id' => 3, 'name' => 'Product C']
        ]
    ]
]);
```

Comment: So the items would appear in multiple groups?

Comment: could you assign a category? in a pivot table

Comment: @Jerodev: yes exactly. i have posted an answer already which should work for my needs. should have fiddled a bit more before asking for help

Answer (score 0):

Ok i figured it out - this should work although i'd need to make sure each items array was ordered by id.

```
        $orders->groupBy(function ($order) {
            return implode('', array_column($order['items'], 'id'));
        });
```